# How do we paint a gist to its full height inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, lit-element

Trying to get the iframe rendering the gist within this `fs-gist` [custom element in this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fs-gist?file=index.html) to expand such that the entire gist shows.

The custom element `fs-gist` has the following host CSS defined:

```
  static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  `;
```

And the iframe that the gist is rendered into has it's inline style defined like this:

```
style="width: 100%; height:100%;"
```

How can we get the gist to fill to its complete height?

The code that renders the gist inside the iframe looks like this:

```
  firstUpdated() {
    let fileName = (this.file) ? this.file : ''; 
    this.iframe.id = 'gist-' + this.gistID;
    
    let doc = (this.iframe.contentDocument || this.iframe.contentWindow) as Document;
      let content = `
        <html>
        <head>
          <base target="_parent">
        </head>
        <body onload="parent.document.getElementById('${this.iframe.id}')">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.github.com/${this.gistID}.js?file=${fileName}"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;
    doc!.open()
    doc!.write(content)
    doc!.close()
  }
```

And the iframe template looks like this:

```
  render() {
    return html`
      <iframe id="gist" type="text/javascript" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
    `;
  }
```

[This is the source code for the custom element `fs-gist`](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/fs-gist/blob/master/src/fs-gist.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body style="height: 100vh;">
  <fs-gist gistID="fireflysemantics/054716730103cd205c39167054542f68">
  </fs-gist>
</body>
```

Setting the height of the body to `100vh` allows the `fs-gist` element to expand within it.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fs-gist-set-body-height-demo

Comment: I see what you mean now.  If the container element has a set height, the gist will expand.

Comment: I updated your answer.  It feels a little "Hacky" but setting container element height as show allows the `fs-gist` element to expand, so that should probably cover most use cases.  I'm going allow the height of the element to be set specifically as well with a `gistHeight` property, so that should be pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [CSS Flex (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp). Here is an example of how I use a flex container for both horizontal and vertical sizing. This is the CSS of the src page 'embedded' in my iFrame and sizes automatically to the height and width. The iFrame is embedded in a Responsive page and sizes accordingly when rotating on a mobile device or resizing the browser window in a desktop.

```
.flex-container-horizontal
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-container-vertical
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 120px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}
```